# Stylelint: Create a rule, that can disallow add nested media queries

Tags: css, sass, stylelint, scss-lint

I wanna create a rule, which should block *nested media queries*.
For example, this SCSS should be blocked:

```
.example-class {
    max-width: 350px;
    @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
         margin: auto;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [write a stylelint plugin](https://stylelint.io/developer-guide/plugins) to disallowed nested at-media rules.

The plugin would walk all the at-media rules in a source and check that their parent is the `root` node. You can use the [PostCSS `walkAtRules()`](https://postcss.org/api/#atrule-walkatrules) to do this, e.g.:

```
root.walkAtRules('media', atRule => {
  if (atRule.parent.type !== "root") {
    stylelint.utils.report({ /* .. */ });
  }
})
```